# SUPABASE- Init local environment - Error: ERROR: schema "vault" does not exist (SQLSTATE 3F000)

Tags: postgresql, next.js, supabase

After using the hosted db, I'm trying to set up a local and staging env but seems not easy as I thought....

I've follow this guide https://supabase.com/docs/guides/cli/managing-environments#deploy-a-migration and after run supabase start I encouraged in this error[image]
anyone can help me?

I've generate the migration supabase/migrations/_remote_commit.sql and pushed to github I'm not able to run supabae locally

Answer (score 0):

I probably found the solution

I've added

-- Name: vault; Type: SCHEMA; Owner: -
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS vault;

before

### --
-- Name: supabase_vault; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: -

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "supabase_vault" WITH SCHEMA "vault";